# how to enable mail function in bitnami lampstack(aws lightsail)

Tags: php, email, lamp, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

My hosting in bitnami lampstack(aws-lightsail), in this mail() is not working.

I enabled the sendmail_path in php.ini located in `/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini`

but also tried with my `admin@mydomain.com` email also yet not worked.

I also created test.php file with a mail function on it. Also this does not work.

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is there any error logged? Can you inspect the mail log to see whether the mail is still queued or got rejected by the next server?